# Страуструп , какую книгу выбрать?

Tags: c++, книги

Прочитал, разобрал и понял половину *Шилдта* "**С++ базовый курс**" а теперь появилось желание перейти на *Страуструпа*, только у него 2 книги "**Принципы и практика использования С++**" а также "**Язык программирования С++**"

P.S. у Шилдта ООП еще не трогал, как раз до него дошел

---

**Дополненение исходя из ответов:** Есть 2 варианта:

**1)** Шилдта бросаю и начинаю "Принципы и практика", а потом "Язык программирования".

**2)** Дочитываю Шилдта и сразу начинаю "Язык программирования".

*Скажите какой выбрать а то мнения разнятся.*

**+P.S.** в "Принципы и практика" ООП вроде как не рассматривается

**+P.S.** сразу начинать "Язык программирования" не хочу, с самого начала идет сложновато пока что для меня

Comment: @risonyo в каком формате читаешь? djvu,pdf,fb2 .....

Comment: В начале нужно прочитать эти книги в режиме "художественной литературы", не особо заморачиваясь на то, что непонятно (но при этом делая себе пометки, когда непонятно). Может быть ещё несколько книг. Потом помедитировать. А после этого взять ту книгу, в которая будет самой понятной и начать прорабатывать ее детальнее.

Comment: Мой совет -- выбросьте Шилдта, почитайте Страуструпа, дальше гляньте в [этот вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/173476/c-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81).

Comment: читаю в печатном формате, 2010 года издание

Comment: @risonyo: Шилдт известен многочисленными фактическими ошибками и введением читателя в заблуждение, причём неверная информация подаётся таким уверенным тоном, что начинающие верят ей. Поищите в англоязычном гугле про него. Вот несколько ссылок: [раз](http://stackoverflow.com/q/391091/276994), [два](http://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html), [три](http://c-faq.com/ansi/avail.html).

Comment: @VladD значит мне лучше выбрать первый вариант да?

Comment: @VladD  @risonyo 

лирическое отступление:
"любой автозавод может производить  как УГ так и отличные автомобили" так и "любой автор может написать и УГ и супер учебник "

есть программисты а есть писатели, иногда первые пишут для новичков а вторые для профессионалов. (и то и то ужасно)

шилдт-писатель потому для новичка это хорошо (легче читать), а для профессионала это глупости. 


что касается шилдта то да у него действительно есть проблемы особенно по С и некоторые по С++ (особенно "справочники") но вот ругательств в сторону "С++ базовый курс" я пока невидел ...

Comment: @risonyo: да, первый вариант предпочтительнее. Я бы ещё посоветовал ["Thinking in C++"](http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) (или русский перевод "Философия С++", только нужен _хороший_ перевод) Брюса Эккеля. У Страуструпа может быть лучше начать с "Принципов и практики", она ориентирована на новичков.

Comment: @VladD спасибо большое и тебе @ProkletyiPirat

Comment: начинайте писать код ... хватит уже читать... практика и только практика... приведут к профессиональному заработку

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прочитай от корки до корки сначала "Принципы и практика использования С++", а все что не понятно или захочешь по больше узнать тонкостей можешь смотреть в "Язык программирования С++".

Answer (score 2):

в fb2 версии, что у меня, ООП начинается с 11-й главы(стр 547\1322)
получается что ты ещё толком ничего не прочитал...

так что лучше дочитай до конца и потренируйся... а уже потом переходи на страуструпа

---

я сам по ней учился, для совсем новенького книга хорошая. Но в ней многого не указано а кое что взрослые программисты в этой  книге назовут "говнокодом" например это

```
three_d operator+(three_d op2); 
three_d operator=(three_d op2);
```

но опять таки для неопытного это как раз "базовый курс".

Comment: как верно подмечено у `skipy.ru` "нельзя запастись знаниями в прок" то есть ты канешно прочтешь  но часть знаний не сможешь осознать, в итоге будут пробелы...

-------------
ты же не будешь учиться водить на болиде F1 ?! сначала ты поучишься  на отечественном тазе который не жалко разбить, а потом уже купишь себе ферари или хамер

Answer (score 2):

Страуструп 4-е издание, так же очень хорошо прочитать Мейерса "Эффективное использование C++" и его же "Эффективное использование STL".

Comment: а 4 издание на русском есть?

Comment: хороший вопрос. но когда-то обязательно будет. но за неимением 4-го пойдет для начала и 3-е, ведь с++11 пока еще не так уж распространен, и всего несколько новейших версий популярных компиляторов его толком поддерживают, и как правило приходится работать не с ними. так что ИМХО предыдущую версию стандарта надо тоже знать.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы передо мной сейчас стоял такой выбор, то я бы начал штудировать "Язык программирования С++" [4-е издание](http://www.amazon.com/The-Programming-Language-4th-Edition/dp/0321563840/). Почему именно его? Ну, во-первых в нём появилось описание нового стандарта, а во-вторых я начинал разбирать 3-е издание, и оно мне жутко понравилось, но поддержки нового стандарта там ещё не было, поэтому пришлось покупать одноимённую книгу С. Прата (6-е издание).

Comment: а 4 издание на русском есть?

Comment: и если купить или скачать 3е то лучше Специальное издание?

Comment: Хе-хе, так там же написано

>This title has not yet been released.

Книга еще не издана, идут предварительные заказы.

Comment: Никто не мешает заказать её и, при условии знания английского, заняться изучением. В "Специальном издании" были добавлены новые приложения и исправлены ошибки, вообще, можно найти описание и почитать)

Comment: Ясно дело. Только согласно анонсу выйти должна в мае. Зачем советовать книгу, которая выйдет только через несколько месяцев?

Comment: Пару причин я написал в своём ответе. Да, преждевременно советовать что-то не очень хорошо, но в данном случае нужно смотреть на то, кто её автор.

Answer (score 1):

У Страуструпа в самом начале дан самый важный совет - Лучший способ научиться программировать - это программировать. Начните уже программировать, хватит книги листать, а в процессе и книга найдётся, та, которая лично вам понятна для восприятия.

Answer (score 0):

Однозначно Страуструп

Comment: @rekrut, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте почитать `Professional C++ (Wrox Professional Guides)`